# Using QGIS to fix invalid geometry without saying not allowed?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, invalid-data

I have a shapefile, and it's got a self-intersecting geometry in it. I'd like to fix the self-intersection, but it will require a few moves. When I attempt to move a point using the QGIS edit tools, I am warned that the resulting geometry is invalid (I know this already) and that my last change has been reverted.

Is there a way to suppress these warnings in QGIS so I can make the change, and only have it enforce validity when I'm done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of QGIS are you using?

QGIS 1.5 'Tethys' (1.5.0) has a fix for 'Allow editing of invalid geometry in node tool'

http://www.qgis.org/en/about-qgis/qgis-releases.html

Comment: I'm on 1.4, but I'm grabbing the new one right now. Thanks for the hint!